# Jenkins to build development branch and check code with sonar

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

I use jenkins to build my maven projects, now I need to use sonar to check my code quality and coverage. My branch strategy for SVN each developer use a branch to develop new features and then this branch is merged on trunk. So before this merge I need to run sonar on a development branch, and I don´t need to run and check full projectm I need to check only the changes on the development branch, sometimes it´s only a revision, sometimes can be more. Sonar it´s able to do this? Anyone have a experience with this?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not currently possible.
What's the issue about running a full analysis of the branch and working with differentials? http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Differential+Views